# Can I install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with 1 GB ram

Tags: 18.04

Can I install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with 1 GB RAM. My desktop computer has 2.99 GHz 32-bit CPU and 1GB RAM.
What Ubuntu version should I install?

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: One of my testing boxes is *dell latitude d610 (pentium m, 1gb, intel i915)*, and I used it up to and including 19.04 (for Lubuntu & Xubuntu testing).  I sure wouldn't run GNOME on it though, and that isn't much memory for some tasks, but the machine still runs. I do have a ibm thinkpad t43 (pentium m, 1.5gb ram, radeon x300) running Lubuntu 18.04 LTS that I still use for some tasks.

Comment: You definitely can't, an installer for Ubuntu 18.04 32 bit does not exist, only installers for 64 bit architecture are provided.

Answer (score 1):

Barely, or no. Use Xubuntu.

> To install and use Xubuntu, you need at least 512 MB of memory.
>   https://xubuntu.org/requirements/.

It's based on debian and ubuntu: https://www.distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=xubuntu